# @RawQuery and Generated RxRoom.createFlowable(db, tables)

Tags: rx-java2, android-room

I'm using RxJava2 and Android's Room framework (v2.1.0).  Ultimately, I'm using the `Flowable` from a `@RawQuery`-annotated `abstract` method in my `@Dao` class.  When I updated a row/column of one of the referenced tables (using an `@Update` method in my `@Dao` on the root entity), I was expecting the `Flowable` to re-trigger when any of the referenced tables in the `@RawQuery` were touched.  However, that didn't seem to be the case.

After digging into the generated code for my `@Dao` class, I noticed that the Room return value is wrapped in a call to [`RxRoom::createFlowable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RxRoom.html#createFlowable(android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase,%20java.lang.String...).  I noticed that the `tableNames` argument only contained a subset of the expected tables names, so it made more sense why my `Flowable` was not re-triggering since I had updated one of the tables outside of the specified subset.

Upon further reflection, it made more sense why the code generator for Room couldn't derive the full set of table names, since all the table names were only available at runtime.  (I wish the `RxRoom` documentation made it more plainly obvious that observing a `@RawQuery` would be flaky w/o using the `observedEntities` annotation argument!)

However, it's still a mystery to me how that subset of table names was even generated.  While I probably could dive into the code base, it'd be great if someone knowledgeable could summarize how `RxRoom` derives the table names from a `@RawQuery`.  My guess is that `RxRoom` is using the "leaf" joined tables of the root entity being queried, but I don't really understand why that's a reasonable default.  IMHO, a safer default would be to NOT observe any referenced tables in a `@RawQuery` unless `observedEntities` is specified.